# How do I programmatically create class methods in Python?

Tags: python, class, namespaces

Suppose I want to define a Python class whose instances have several members of similar form:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.baz=3
        self.x=1
        self.name=4
```

I can instead create all members at once using explicit manipulation of `__dict__`:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__.update({name: len(name) for name in ("baz", "x", "name")})
```

However, if the associated members are *class* data members, instead of instance members, then I am aware of no analogous way to programmatically mutate `Bar.__dict__`:

```
class Bar:
    #Fails with "AttributeError: 'mappingproxy' object has no attribute 'update'"
    Bar.__dict__.update({name: len(name) for name in ("baz", "x", "name")})
```

In Javascript, programmatically manipulating the properties of a constructor is possible, because constructors are just ordinary functions, which are just ordinary objects, and therefore just a mutable dictionary mapping properties to more objects.  Is it possible to write analogous code in Python?

Comment: `setattr(Bar, 'baz', 3)` seems to work in Python3.10?

Comment: @IainShelvington: Fascinating.  I didn't remember `setattr`, and I'm surprised it can modify an unmodifyable dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use a metaclass, a base class with `__init_subclass__` *or* use `eval` to create your class. Here's an example using a base class:

```py
class Base:
    attrs_to_set: set[str] = set()

    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
        for attr in cls.attrs_to_set:
            setattr(cls, attr, cls.get_attr_value(attr))

    @classmethod
    def get_attr_value(cls, attr_name: str):
        # default, you can change it depending on your use case i guess.
        return len(attr_name)


class Bar(Base):
    attrs_to_set = {"x", "baz", "name"}


print(Bar.x, Bar.name, Bar.baz)
# prints: 1 4 3
```

Comment: The key tool here is that `setattr` works to modify `Bar.__dict__`, but your metaclass offers the nicety that I don't need to wait until after the class definition to apply it.  TY!